# Antonym of "Condescending" or "Patronizing"

Tags: antonyms

Are there any proper antonyms for the words "condescending" or "patronizing"? (assuming equivalent definition)

An easy Google search provides "Humble, Friendly" etc. But they don't seem to fit well.

Comment: Do you mean as an adjective? Can you give an example of how you would use it?

Comment: You should indicate whether you are looking for verbs or adjectives because both "condescending" and "patronizing" are both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respectful

Respect

See the definitions and synonyms given for verb 1 and 2 [here.](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=define+respect&oq=define+respect)

Admiring

Honoring

Acknowledging

Answer (score 1):

*deferential*   adj.  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deferential

   respectful and considerate

   showing deference

   based on the doctrine, ideology, or wishes of others rather than one's own conclusions